# Who machine gunned the Saviours that Carol was being held at gunpoint by?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

I'm still a bit confused, in late Season 6 of **The Walking Dead**, Carol went away from the community for certain reasons, she had a car with wooden spikes protruding from it (even the bonnet) when she comes across a car with around four men in it (who turn out to be Saviours), her back tire is shot out leaving the car stranded and her trapped.

She lies about her identity but the Saviours already know she is from Alexandria because of the car.

Some time has passed when all of a sudden, automatic fire comes from nowhere (it wasn't Carol as she had only a hand gun) but only one of the men in the car survived, and he goes after her in the field and later attacks her.

***If Carol didnt gun them down, then who did?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The episode is called "[East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_(The_Walking_Dead))" (Season 6, Episode 15), and it is in fact Carol who gunned them down, using a machine gun hidden in her sleeve.